# Redirect parent page from iframe in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, redirect, iframe, mobile-safari

I'm embedding an iFrame to an external payment-provider, after the user completes their step the user gets redirected to my domain.
I'm now trying to redirect the parent page to another page located on my domain like so:

**iFrame embedded on mydomain.com**

```
<iframe src="example.com/payment" sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-forms allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

**Code to redirect the parent page**

```
window.top.location.href = "mydomain.com";
```

On Safari in iOS I'm now getting: **SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.**

Is this the expected behavior even though I used *allow-top-navigation* in my sandbox parameter?
If so, are there any existing workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself.
My iframe sandbox attribute was missing the: **allow-same-origin** Parameter

**Working Example**

```
<iframe src="example.com/payment" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation allow-forms allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

**Explanation**

From what I understand the problem was the redirect of:
*example.com/payment* to *mydomain.com* this gets prevented by some browsers.
Sadly I found no clear explanation on why this particular redirect is prevented.
It seems to be related to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy